# Elements sometimes hide and than appear again

Tags: css, macos, safari, osx-yosemite

When I visit following page with a Mac OS X Yosemite with Safari 8, than some elements on the page just disappear and sometimes magically appears again.

URL: http://editz.de/landingpage/

The page is splitted into 4 blocks.

If you open the page, the first "welcome" block appears normaly. If you scroll down, every other block is not visible. If you wait and play a bit with the page, suddenly the blocks appear. Sometimes if you play around the first "welcome" black disappears too.

Same page in Chrome works perfect like wanted.

I don't know if this is a browser bug from Safari or just something I didn't take care inside the css for Safari browsers.

Comment: It works fine for me (latest Firefox). Can't check on Safari since I'm on Windows, but I will when I get home. Are you maybe running an ad blocker or similar extension that might be injecting CSS rules into your webpage?

Comment: Works fine here on Safari , Yosemite. Also there was recent update for OS X 10.10.2, which i got last week and now safari is not having lagging issues anymore.

Comment: It works on every "normal" browser, just not in Safari. @poush can you please try to refresh the page, scroll to another position and refresh again to "force" the bug? I would say it could be a 10.10.1 bug, but it's not working in earlier versions too.. I tested it with browserstack, but my free account is expired.

Comment: lol yea it is happening as same as you are saying after force refreshes :P. But clicking any other button loads full page correctly again

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Safari has problems with the z-index value.

To fix it, you have to add following CSS-Code to every element which has a relative position.

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This worked for me.